# Unable to obtain instance from null - PicketLink

Tags: java, picketlink

We are getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: WELD-000044 Unable to obtain instance from null
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.CallableMethodHandler.invoke(CallableMethodHandler.java:48)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.weldx.persistence.EntityManager$1841842027$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManager$1841842027$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
[ERROR]     at org.picketlink.idm.jpa.internal.JPAIdentityStore.getPartitions(JPAIdentityStore.java:298)
[ERROR]     at org.picketlink.idm.jpa.internal.JPAIdentityStore.get(JPAIdentityStore.java:290)
[ERROR]     at org.picketlink.idm.internal.DefaultPartitionManager.getPartitions(DefaultPartitionManager.java:325)
[ERROR]     ... 80 more
```

And investigating, I can see that this is the root cause:

**DefaultPartionManager.java**

Method that throws error:

```
public <T extends Partition> List<T> getPartitions(Class<T> partitionClass)
```

Here:

```
throw MESSAGES.partitionGetFailed(partitionClass, "not specified", e);
```

However I am confused about this error when we have set the PartitionTypeEntity.class in the IDMConfiguration.java:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class IDMConfiguration {
    @Inject
    private EEJPAContextInitializer contextInitializer;

    private IdentityConfiguration identityConfig = null;

    @Produces
    IdentityConfiguration createConfig() {
        if (identityConfig == null) {
            initConfig(null);
        }
        return identityConfig;
    }

    public void configureIdentityManagement(@Observes IdentityConfigurationEvent event) {
        initConfig(event.getConfig());
    }

        public void initConfig(IdentityConfigurationBuilder builder){
        if (builder == null){
            builder = new IdentityConfigurationBuilder();
        }
        builder.named("default" + "").stores().jpa().mappedEntity(
                    AccountTypeEntity.class,
                    RoleTypeEntity.class,
                    GroupTypeEntity.class,
                    IdentityTypeEntity.class,
                    RelationshipTypeEntity.class,
                    RelationshipIdentityTypeEntity.class,
                    PartitionTypeEntity.class,
                    PasswordCredentialTypeEntity.class,
                    AttributeTypeEntity.class)
                    //UserImpl.class)
                .supportGlobalRelationship(Relationship.class)
                .addContextInitializer(this.contextInitializer)
                .setCredentialHandlerProperty(PasswordCredentialHandler.SUPPORTED_ACCOUNT_TYPES_PROPERTY, UserImpl.class)

                .supportAllFeatures();
        identityConfig = builder.build();
    }

}
```

Comment: And can see in the trace: [ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: PLIDM000404: Could not load partition for type [interface org.picketlink.idm.model.Partition] and name [not specified].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your database, is there a entry for a "default" PartitionTypeEntity? I think you should check to see if it exists before you start using it.  Picketlink is supposed to automatically create a default partition the first time you use it but I guess sometimes it doesn't do it for you.   For me, in an `IDMInitializer`, I had to check if there was a "default" partition first and if there wasn't, I had to create a new `Realm()` before I start using the application.

```
    @Singleton
    @Startup
    public class IDMInitializer{
    @Inject
    private PartitionManager partitionManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
            Realm defaultReam = this.partitionManager.getPartition(Realm.class, "default");
            if (defaultReam==null){
                    System.out.println("Couldn't find default partition, creating default partition");
                    defaultRealm = new Realm("default");
                    this.partitionManager.add(defaultRealm);
            } else {
                    System.out.println("Found default partition");
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, been facing this same issue, and went ahead to manually add the said "default" partittion type to the table. Here's what i have in the db: http://hastebin.com/qifiweganu.rb But still get the error `PLIDM000404: Could not load partition for type [class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Realm] and name [default].` How should the value be added to the DB table?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look more deeply into what it exactly needs.  In my persistence.xml, I set the schema to auto generate so that picket link would create the tables for me. and then you need to have some kind of initializing function before you can use things.  I think it came from one of the quickstarts they have.